# Use # (Copy) as selection or filter on 2-d array

Tags: j

The J primitive [**Copy**](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help807/dictionary/d400.htm) (`#`) can be used as a filter function, such as

```
k =: i.8
(k>3) # k
4 5 6 7
```

That's essentially

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 # i.8
```

The question is if the right-hand side of `#` is 2-d or higher rank shaped array, how to make a selection using `#`, if possible.  For example:

```
k =: 2 4 $ i.8

(k > 3) # k
```

I got `length error`

What is the right way to make such a selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the appropriate verb rank to get something like a 2d-selection:

```
(2 | k) #"1 1 k
1 3
5 7
```

but the requested axes have to be filled with `0`s (or `!.`) to keep the correct shape:

```
(k > 3) #("1 1) k
0 0 0 0
4 5 6 7

(k > 2) #("1 1) k
3 0 0 0
4 5 6 7
```

You have to better define `select` for dimensions > 1 because now you have a structure. How do you discard values? Do you keep empty "cells"? Do you replace with `0`s? Is structure important for the result?

If, for example, you only need the "values where" then just ravel `,` the array:

```
(,k > 2) # ,k
3 4 5 6 7
```

If you need to "replace where", then you can use amend `}`:

```
u =: 5 :'I. , 5 >  y'     NB. indices where 5 > y
0 u } k
0 0 0 0
0 5 6 7

z =: 3 2 4 $ i.25
u =: 4 :'I. , (5 > y) +. (0 = 3|y)'     NB. indices where 5>y or 3 divides y
_999 u } z
_999 _999 _999 _999
_999    5 _999    7

  8 _999   10   11
_999   13   14 _999

 16   17 _999   19
 20 _999   22   23
```